# When, if ever, to use the Ruby keyword "for"

Tags: ruby, for-loop, coding-style, each, keyword

I personally like to iterate using the `for` keyword in Ruby since it reads very clean, from my eye. I generally assume that `for` may be an alias to `Enumerable#each`, but I do not know whether is is correct. In the most basic example:

```
for i in (1..10)
  puts i
end
```

behaves the same as

```
(1..10).each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

just without creating a new variable scope. Moreover, [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-for+Loop) says

> The `for` loop is rarely used in modern ruby programs.

which makes me feel there is a specific, technical reason against the usage. Does it matter that there's no new variable scope? In what way?

Comment: Check out the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-for-loops) for an explanation and example.

Comment: Your description is a little bit contradicting. On the one hand, you admit that it is **your personal liking** to use `for`. Then, you wrote it is clean **from [any] programmer's eye**. After all, it is just your personal opinion. Most people who understand Ruby prefer `each` over `for` and consider `each` to be cleaner than `for` to their eyes. You just seem to have a weird opinion.

Comment: "from the programmer's eye". From *your* programmer's eye. Every language has its idiomatic uses, and it's good to learn them if you ever intend to share, or even reveal, your code. While we all have our own favorite ways of speaking, knowing how to speak correctly in a particular spoken langauge is important, and the same is true when writing in a programming language. The Ruby Style Guide(s) are very good starting points.

Comment: Personally I also prefer the look of `for`, and in early days of Ruby, `for` performed better. Nowadays, since `each` was changed, it seems to perform better by a small margin. `for` should probably also undergo a fix to remove the leaked local var, but it would break so much code to do so, it won't likely happen. If you want the fastest iteration in Ruby 2, a `while` loop is probably the way to go (idioms aside). I personally avoid style guides that dictate based on idiom, and just use what is maintainable and performant, first. My problem with `for` isn't its appearance, its the side effect.

Comment: @codenheim, I don't believe the leaking of variables is a bug that needs fixing. Its behavior is consistent with that of other constructs such as `if` and `while`. I believe this is by design. As such, I don't think it comes down to a simple issue of aesthetics and subjective opinions; the semantic differences may come in handy, just like the distinct precedences of `||` and `or`. Ruby developers should understand both forms.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira - I didn't call it a bug. Though I agree that it is a simple enough semantic issue for Ruby developers to be aware of without shying away from `for` as the style guide causes people to do, there is not an alternative `for` syntax to use a locally scoped iterator without code block overhead of `each`. It should, ideally, be possible to write a `for` loop that runs as fast as the `while` in Ruby.

Comment: @sawa and @theTinMan yes, *my* "programmer's eye", not *any* "programmer's eye". But I wouldn't call it "weird", just an opinion. What I'm really after is the technical argument for the use of `for` over `each`, or visa versa.

Comment: `since each was changed, it seems to perform better by a small margin`

@codenheim could you explain how `each` has changed since the early days? I have only been programming Ruby since ~2010, so it would be helpful if you could contribute that background in an answer (for myself and other younger programmers).

Comment: @haiqus - Sure, I'll write up an answer today. Gotta run at the moment, Saturday morning errands. In case I forget, ping me at my email if you don't see something from me within say 4-6 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> behaves the same as

This is incorrect. `for` is built on top of `each`, but it is semantically distinct:

```
array = %w(a b c d)

array.each { |character| }
defined? character            # nil

for character in array; end
defined? character            # "local-variable"
```

The `for` keyword doesn't introduce a new scope. Any variables introduced inside the block remain visible outside of it; as if it was written inline.

You should take this fact into account when you decide which form to use.

Comment: `Any variables introduced inside the block remain visible outside of it; as if it was written inline.`

That seems to be the key distinction. Thanks @Matheus